# For a bipartite operator $M\in L(H_{AB})$, suppose $0\leq M\leq \mathbb{I}$. Prove $M^{AB}\leq M^A\otimes \mathbb{I}$

Tags: measurement, quantum-operation, linear-algebra

As stated in the title, let $M$ be a linear operator on a finite bipartite Hilbert space. Suppose $0\leq M^{AB}\leq \mathbb{I}$ and $0\leq M^A,M^B\leq\mathbb{I}$, where $M^A=\mathrm{Tr}_B\left(M^{AB}\right)$ and $M^B=\mathrm{Tr}_A\left(M^{AB}\right)$. Is it always true that
$$ M^{AB} \leq M^A\otimes \mathbb{I}_B? $$
It trivially holds for product operators, that is $M^{AB} = M^A\otimes M^B$, but the general statement is not clear to me.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not true.
Just take Bell state $M^{AB} = |v\rangle\langle v|$, where  $|v\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)$. It has eigenvalue 1.
But $M^A \otimes I_2= \frac{1}{2}I_2 \otimes I_2 = \frac{1}{2}I_4$.

Comment: $M^{AB}$ doesn't even have to be entangled, it can be the product of two pure states and still have eigenvalue 1.

Comment: But in such a case the inequality will hold.

Comment: Oh, you are assuming that $M^A=\mathrm{Tr}_B (M^{AB})$? That wasn't explicit in the question but it definitely helps motivate the question.

Comment: @QuantumMechanic Yes, that is indeed what I meant. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 2):

No, but it is true that
$$M^{AB} \le d\, M^A \otimes  \mathbb{I}_B,$$
where $d$ is the minimum of $d_A$ and $d_B$. This inequality is tight in the sense that entangled states saturate it, as the other answer shows. A proof can be found in Appendix A of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.10526).